# how to bind bootstrap loading button success / error on form submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to bind a bootstrap button with loading state to a form.
I would like the button to keep the data-loading state until the form is submitted. If the form errors out the data-loading should ideally stop or display a different message.
How can I achieve this?

My code for the button:

http://www.bootply.com/128762

what would be the best approach for a form that is not ajax?

Answer (score 0):

Are You looking Something Like this Below

```js
$('#loading-example-btn').click(function () {
  if($("#txt").val().length > 0)
    { 
    var btn = $(this)
   $(this).attr('value','Loading');                           
    }
    else 
    {
    $(this).attr('value','error On Submit'); 
    }
    
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="post">
<input type="text" name="test" id="txt">
<input type="submit" id="loading-example-btn" value="Submit" data-loading-text="Loading...">
</form>
```